# dyld: Library not loaded when using Qt QtWebEngine

Tags: qt, qtwebengine

I am getting this error when trying to run my app after using macdeployqt.

dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick
Referenced from: /x/build-x-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_clang_64bit-Release/x.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineCore
Reason: image not found

It only happens with a QtWebEngine app. I have another that builds just fine usingn QtWebKit.

My otool results seem fine:

jimmys-MacBook-Air:osx jimmy$ otool -L /development/_build_desktop/Application-Screensaver/Webshots\ Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/Desktop 
/development/_build_desktop/Application-Screensaver/Webshots Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/Desktop:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 20.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 48.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1056.16.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/Versions/A/StoreKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 232.11.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineWidgets (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.2)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngine (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.2)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.2)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.2)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.2)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/QtQml.framework/Versions/5/QtQml (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.2)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.2)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.2)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineCore (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.2)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 60.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1265.21.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 855.17.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 59.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)

Thanks,
Jimmy

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, looks like the answer is in this bug report:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41611

> If your application includes QtWebEngine the macdeployqt application should also deploy QtWebEngineProcess and the support files needed. Currently this needs to be done manually.
>
> FOR 5.4 YOU MUST RUN macdeployqt THE FOLLOWING WAY:
>
> ```
> macdeployqt <TARGET>.app -executable=<TARGET>.app/Contents/MacOS/<TARGET>
> ```
>
> macdeployqt only uses @loader_path when the -executable switch is non-empty, so passing an arbitrary exectable there triggers the behavior we need to let QtWebEngineProcess use the same Qt binaries as the main application executable.