# How to make macdeployqt change the library names inside QtWebEngineProcess.app when it copies over QtWebEngineCore framework

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qtwebengine, macdeployqt

Edit: using Qt 5.9.1, installed with Homebrew

Following a comment in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46406477/1027706), we are trying to use `macdeployqt` to prepare the distribution of the OSX bundle of a Qt based application.

This tool is correctly copying over all Qt dependencies (and even some non Qt libraries) inside the bundle. It also changes the dependent library names inside both the application itself and the copied libraries.

It also successfully copies the *QtWebEngineProcess.app* contained in the *Helpers* folder of *QtWebEngineCore.framework*.

### Problem

A problem is that it is not changing the dependent library names **inside** *QtWebEngineProcess*, so the bundle is not relocatable (as *QtWebEngineProcess* refers to its dependent library by absolute paths that are only valid on the development machine).
Trying to run the app on a "client" machine, one would thus get the error:

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineCore
>   Referenced from: Business.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/QtWebEngineProcess

We tried to manually fix this application, by editing QtWebEngineProcess to replace the absolute part of the path to the Qt libraries by `@loader_path/../../../../../../../../Frameworks/`.

This only moves the problem forward: now *QtWebEngineProcess* seems to correctly load its dependent libraries, but the dependent libraries themselves cannot load their dependent libraries anymore, since their install name is starting with **@executable_path**, and *QtWebEngineProcess* executable lives in a different folder from *Business* executable. Hence the error:

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick
>   Referenced from: Business.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineCore

---

Is **macdeployqt** broken when it comes to an application using Qt's web engine?

Is there a way to have it work without manually re-changing all Qt install names in the bundle?

Comment: Not sure it would help in your case too but for my application using `QtWebEngine` I run `macdeployqt` first and then I run `install_name_tool` with option `-add rpath @executable_path/../Frameworks <absolute path to app install dir>/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp` where `MyApp.app` is the name of the application bundle and `MyApp` is the name of the application binary.

Comment: @Dmitry Sadly as we see in the second error, the Qt libraries contain install names to their dependent Qt libraries that start with `@executable_path`, not with `@rpath` (this is done by `macdeployqt`). So I guess populating the rpath of the application should not make a difference.

Comment: I can see you use Qt installed via Homebrew. Have you tried to use the official Qt installation package instead?

Comment: @Dmitry That is an interesting suggestion. I found some nasty workaround for the moment, but the official Qt installation is a track to investigate, thank you!

Comment: @AdN Could you please share your workaround as an answer? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @Dmitry Thank you for your suggestion, you were right, the official distribution of Qt makes it work!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded when using Qt QtWebEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677457/dyld-library-not-loaded-when-using-qt-qtwebengine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following one of Dmitry's comment on the original question, I finally took the time to test with an official distribution of Qt 5.9.1 for OS X, and it turns out he was right. The `macdeployqt`distributed with the official binaries of Qt is handling QtWebEngineProcess.app just fine.

The version of this utility distributed with `homebrew` installation's of Qt is bogus, at least in 5.9.1

Answer (score 0):

So far `macdeployqt` works fine for me on local machine.
On CI you might encounter problem that artifacts are broken in somewhat way like this.

That happens if you copy your application with `cp -r` or `zip` it without `-y` option then all symlinks will be resolved inside the app and it won't work because there will be many copies of `QtWebEngineProcess`. Also it will break your signature if you sign app.

Solution is to use `cp -a` and `zip -r -y` instead - the last one worked for me instead of using plugin for artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

I've crafted a following script, which fixes these paths with `install_name_tool`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -x -e

pushd MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app/Contents/MacOS

for LIB in QtGui QtCore QtWebEngineCore QtQuick QtWebChannel QtQml QtNetwork QtPositioning
do
    OLD_PATH=`otool -L QtWebEngineProcess | grep ${LIB} | cut -f 1 -d ' '`
    NEW_PATH="@loader_path/../../../../../../../${LIB}.framework/${LIB}"
    install_name_tool -change ${OLD_PATH} ${NEW_PATH} QtWebEngineProcess
done

popd
```

Note the lack of quotes around `${OLD_PATH}` when used as an `install_name_tool` argument. This is because value of `OLD_PATH` has some extra white spaces around the path, which shouldn't be preserved. The lack of quotes is typically harmless if Qt has been installed via Homebrew, as these paths do not contain white spaces. However, this could be improved.

**Important**:  This fix is enough to make Simple Browser (from Qt examples) running.  But in more advanced projects, more fiddling may be required.